# I need some help in a query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause

I need a query that filters from the first day of the previous month and the current day at 0 hours.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use date arithmetics:

```
where mydate >= dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate()),month(getdate()), 1))
```

Expression `datefromparts(year(getdate()),month(getdate()), 1)` gives you the first day of the current month; you can then substract 1 month to get the result that you want.

If you want to filter out today's data (and beyond), then:

```
where 
    mydate >= dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate()),month(getdate()), 1))
    and mydate < cast(getdate() as date)
```